# Moshe Judges דָּבָר הַגָּדֹל or דָּבָר הַקָּשֶׁה

Tags: parashas-yisro, moshe-rabbeinu, parshanut-torah-comment

In the first Posuk it says:

וְשָׁפְטוּ אֶת הָעָם בְּכָל עֵת וְהָיָה כָּל הַדָּבָר הַגָּדֹל יָבִיאוּ אֵלֶיךָ

Then in the later Posuk it says:

אֶת הַדָּבָר הַקָּשֶׁה יְבִיאוּן אֶל מֹשֶׁה

The question is whats the diffrence and why does it say both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbi Chaim Berlin says that by a non Jew the value of a court case is dependent on the value of the claim, however by a Jew there is no difference in the value of the claim "Din Peruta Kedin Meyah". Yisro suggested that Moshe should take care of the big cases - literally the cases that involve large sums. Moshe took care of the difficult cases - which was not only cases involving large sums.

Comment: I wonder - do modern Batei Din treat large- and small-value cases with similar Halachic characteristics similarly?